# Mongoose query with multiple $or condition and array as parameter

Tags: node.js, database, mongoose, select, schema

I'm making the followed/following rules to simulate a blog/social like app, but I want to suggest to to the users only people that are not following or followed by this user, but any combination haven't worked out yet. The Schema is:

```
const Follower = new mongoose.model('Follower', new mongoose.Schema({    
    sent: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: User,
        required: true
    },
    received: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: User,
        required: true
    },
    pending: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: true
    }
}))
```

So, if I already sent invitation, or if the user already sent me invitation, should be excluded from the list of suggestions to follow.

So, I select 100 id's from database, but not my id, of course:

`const users = await User.find({ '_id': { $ne: id }}).select('_id').limit(100)`

I put these id's on an array:

```
let ids = []
users.forEach(user => {
    ids.push(user._id)
})
```

Now, I must exclude from this array of id's all users that already sent or received invitations by the user logged in, but the query returns empty:

```
// id from user logged in
const id = req.id

let followers = await Follower.find({ 
    $or: [{sent: id}, {received: {$in: ids}}],
    $or: [{sent: {$in: ids}}, {received: id}]
})
```

I've tried other queries, but to no avail. Any hints, suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not reproduce your specific schema but have you tested with:

```
Follower.find({
  $and: [
    { $or: [{ sent: id }, { received: { $in: ids } }] },
    { $or: [{ sent: { $in: ids } }, { received: id }] },
  ],
});
```

Cause it seems that not using `$and` is making the query ignore your second `$or`. I've tested with sample data below:

```
const main = async () => {
  await connectDB();
  const Test = new mongoose.model(
    "test",
    new mongoose.Schema({
      sent: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      },
      received: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      },
    })
  );

  function getRandomInt(max = 10) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  }

  const sampleDatabaseSize = 100;
  for (i = 0; i < sampleDatabaseSize; i++) {
    await Test.create({
      sent: getRandomInt(),
      received: getRandomInt(),
    });
  }

  id = 4;
  ids = [1, 2, 3];
  result = await Test.find({
    $and: [
      { $or: [{ sent: id }, { received: { $in: ids } }] },
      { $or: [{ sent: { $in: ids } }, { received: id }] },
    ],
  });
  console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes, I've tested this query also, but still returns empty []

Comment: I believe that your data is missing ones that fulfill the query rather than it's a syntactical error.